# Boolean Algebra simplify problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am reading a section on Boolean algebra in a  text book and trying to understand a solution to simplifying problem they have presented.the expression

$$(¬p ∧ ¬q ∨ p)$$

is simplified to
$$(¬q ∧ p).$$

I have not been able to work out what law was used t o arive at this.
Thanks in advance.
PS I am very new to Boolean algebra in case you couldn't tell.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the result is what you wrote?

because I am getting this as $$p \lor \lnot q$$

The procedure is very simple:

We have this expression $$\left(\lnot p \land \lnot q\right) \lor p$$
By the distributive law : => You can find about it here: [Laws of boolean algebra](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjxh-Xfp5_eAhVRhRoKHbvQAsQQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fintrocs.cs.princeton.edu%2Fjava%2F71boolean%2F&psig=AOvVaw3FgLd3xGkKdCwmN2avUe30&ust=1540478474830334)

We get : $$\left(p \lor \lnot p \right) \land \left(p \lor \lnot q \right)$$
In the same link  above we can find that $ p \lor \lnot p = 1$
then: $$1 \land \left(p \lor \lnot q \right)$$
Again from the link we get: $$p \lor \lnot q$$

Good luck!

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a MathJax tutorial; it's pretty easy to pick up and will help your posts here be more readable and look more professional.

Answer (score 0):

By the second distributive law $$ (x y +z )=(x+z)(y+z)$$ or, in $∧ , ∨ $ notation,   $$(x∧y∨z)=((x∨z)∧(y∨z))$$ is   $$(¬p ∧ ¬q ∨ p)=(¬p ∨ p ) ∧ (¬q ∨ p)=\quad1∧ (¬q ∨ p )= (¬q ∨ p). $$